# Filename specification not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a `FileResult` class inspired by a SO post that looks like this:

```
public class FileResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly Stream _content;
    private readonly string _contentType;
    private readonly string _filename;
    private readonly HttpStatusCode _status;

    public FileResult(Stream content, string filename, string contentType = null, HttpStatusCode status = HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        _filename = filename;
        _contentType = contentType;
        _content = content;
        _status = status;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(_status)
                {
                    Content = new StreamContent(_content)
                };

                var contentType = _contentType ?? MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(_filename);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = _filename,
                    Size = _content.Length
                };
                response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = _content.Length;

                return response;
            },
            cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I wire this up in my web api controller like this:

```
[Route("~/campaigns/{campaignId}/creativetemplate")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBulkEditSheetForCampaign(int campaignId)
{
    var sheetStream = await _creativeBulkOperationService.GenerateBulkCreativeEditSpreadsheet(campaignId);
    return new FileResult(sheetStream, $"CreativeEditSheet_{campaignId}.xslx");
}
```

When I call this with my RESTful client, the file is saved as `creativetemplate`. I would expect it to be saved as something resembling `CreativeEditSheet_1234567890.xslx`. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a client-side behavior?

Comment: Looks like a client side behavior, the client possibly just ignores the `Content-disposition` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the consensus is I did this correctly, but the client I am using is ignoring it... which is both good news (I didn't screw anything up) and bad news (now I have to find a better client).

Thanks to all who investigated.